# Modify search function in WordPress (TwentyTwelve)

Tags: functions, customization, search

I want to remove "Search for" text from search form in TwentyTwelve, to wrap in in a div for styling, and probably to play with php a bit – and I'd appreciate some advice on how to do that best.

My "sub-questions within a question":

1) Where is the main search function is located?

2) Should I create a separate custom file, add code to functions.php - or is it okay in this case to just edit the original search function?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: That text is in search.php for the theme, no? If you don't want changes getting lost, look into [child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: Actually, @t31os, that text is not in search.php. That file controls the search results, and I'm looking for ways to modify the search form. Would appreciate more advice from you!

Comment: s_ha_dum has you covered, see [`get_search_form`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify the `searchform.php`, or create one in a child theme (recommended), and you should be able to modify the form all you want.

This is [the file that `get_search_form` looks for](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L152) and is the file used by the default search widget, though it [is not listed in the Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

## Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form

Comment: Thank you, @s_ha_dum. You're saying "modify search form.php" – but where is that form? I can't find it anywhere. The codex says, If you don't have searchform.php in your Theme, WordPress will render its built-in search form. Could you tell me where is that code that generates the default form?

Comment: If there is no file named `searchform.php` in your theme then create one. The default HTML is in `/wp-includes/general-template.php`, to which I have already linked, but don't edit that. It is a Core file. Copy the markup into your `searchform.php` if you need a place to start.