# Custom Post Type Search

Tags: functions, search

I am new to wordpress and need to modify the default search functionality. What file do I have to look for or provide  me with some tutorials..

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `searchform.php`, or create one in a child theme (recommended), and you should be able to modify the form all you want.

The default HTML is in `/wp-includes/general-template.php`, to which I have already linked, but don't edit that. It is a Core file. Copy the markup into your `searchform.php` if you need a place to start.

Please refer [this link to modify search function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97849/modify-search-function-in-wordpress-twentytwelve)  detail.

Also refer [this link for adding custom post type in search](http://www.shilling.id.au/2011/06/23/wordpress-search-only-show-post-and-not-pages/).

Comment: Please use a little more descriptive anchors than "this link", it makes answer more readable and easier to know where link leads to.

Answer (score 0):

Example -
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Example

(ensure you have these parameters true :

`'publicly_queryable' => true,  'query_var' => true,`

then you might need to have this function to include search code in functions.php for custom post types:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filterr');
function search_filterr($query) 
    {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) 
        {
            global $cts,$lang; $arrs=array(); foreach($cts['post_Typess'] as $befefeb) {$arrs[]=$befefeb;}
            if ( $query->is_search ) 
                {
                $arrs[]='post';
                $arrs[]='page';
                $query->set('post_type',  $arrs );

                    //include only specific categories
                    //global $sxvaa,$lang;
                    //$query->set('cat', '' );
                }

            else
                {
                $arrs[]='post';
                $arrs[]='page';
                $query->set('post_type', $arrs  );
                }
        return $query;
        }
    }
```